# Close Vote, Belongs on another site, should not require target site

Tags: bug, close-reasons

This has been a problem with Seasoned Advice for quite some time, and despite it being [reported for 6 years](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1891) remains unresolved and unaddressed.

We get a lot of questions that really belong on another SE Site.  However, the "Close: Belongs on another site" option only lets us choose Meta.  According to the other question, the SE interface only allows us to designate up to 5 other SE boards, so we can't cover all the probable ones.

As such, the obvious solution is to make this option "Close:Belongs on another site" with no site option specified or required.  Since this is a "community-specific reason" it should be in the powers of our Moderators to address.  No?

Answer (score 1):

The even simpler approach is to use either a custom flag where you can suggest a target site, a custom close reason, or just close as off-topic.

The number of migration candidates is so small that moderator flags are not causing any overload issues for the moderator team. As a side note we often double-check with the moderator team of the target site whether the question meets the rules, i.e. is on topic and meets the minimum quality requirements. A blind migration where the post gets immediately closed again and then is pushed back to us etc. is a very negative experience for the asker, especially considering that the questions are often posted by new(-ish) users that aren’t familiar with the SE system and its sites.

Technically, closing as “off-topic” would be also correct and sufficient, migration is a service we provide to the users. A blank “belongs to another unspecified site” is a just subset of “off-topic” and covered by that close reason.

Comment: That's fine, but in that case, remove the "belongs on another site" option.  It's just bad UX to have it be there, but nonfunctional.

Comment: Letting you in on a small detail: Mods access an extended UI when using the “belongs on another site” close reason. There we can select the specific migration target across the network, *after checking that migrating is the appropriate action*. And migrating to a site’s meta is still useful when it can be handled by the community sans necessary mod involvement.

Comment: @Stephie : That's horrible UX to have someone see an option that's basically "oh, that's what I want ... but wait, I can't specify gardening, or whatever useful", and then have to put it in as "other".  If the person isn't a moderator, it could always just create a message for the moderator about where the person submitting the complaint thinks the post should go, but require a moderator to actually trigger the move.